# "window.performance.timing.navigationStart" is showing deprecated now. what is the alternative for this in es6?

Tags: javascript

[depracated example][1]

"window.performance.timing.navigationStart" is showing deprecated now. what is the alternative for this in es6?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AySXQ.png

Comment: Just a nitpick: [Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) is a Web API, it has nothing to do with JS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Quoth [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/navigationStart):

> Warning: This interface of this property is deprecated in the Navigation Timing Level 2 specification. Please use the [PerformanceNavigationTiming interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming) instead.